# Android stop users from leaving fragment

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to stop users from leaving a fragment (clicking back button, navigating to other fragment from navigation, etc)?

The situation is that when the user clicks to backup files to USB device, backup process is started (Thread) and if he leave this fragment, some awkward things happen to the backup process and the app crashes.

I was thinking if I could use some of the lifecycle callbacks like:

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //Do something to stop user from leaving
    }
```

or

Is there another way to handle this situation and provide the best possible UX (maybe some dialog fragments involvement)?

Comment: You can override the behavior of the back button in the Activity.  But really, it sounds like your architecture is wrong here-  leaving the fragment shouldn't break the backup process.  The backup process should be a background task, and the fragment just a UI that shows while it happens.  You should fix your architecture instead of throwing a bandaid on it

Comment: I'm updating the UI while backup is in progress and when I move to another fragment one of the problems is null objects. For example, getActivity().runOnUiThread(...) throws NullPointerException

Comment: you have to run long-running jobs on background threads so the main thread won't freeze.

Comment: That can be fixed.  First off, you shouldn't have your backup code actually in your UI code, use proper separation of concerns.  BackupManager.startOperation() or something like that should be called from your fragment.  Secondly, don't call getActivity all the time like that.  Do it once on fragment start, and save the Application context in a variable.  Then use that context for all the backup functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I wrapped getActivity().runOnUiThread() inside try...catch block. I know my architecture isn't good, but I have time for which I have to complete some tasks and I'm not a mobile developer that's why I'll go with the fastest way.

Answer (score 1):

you can override the method on the back with help of a flag indicating if the backup process is done or not

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if(backUpFinished)
       super.onBackPressed()   
}
```

but, your saving backup shouldn't be related to the fragment